# MySQL connection with VB.NET via internet!

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection

I'm being able to connect to mysql database in localhost. But not able to connect in my server? Please can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670949/remote-mysql-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the error : "Unable to connect to any of the specified MYSQL hosts.", you need allow ip address in mysql server which can be done via cpanel.