# How to access mysql data through java by using IP address as Host name?

Tags: java, mysql

```
    String name = "";
    String port = "3306";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    String dbname = "atm";
    String host="192.168.5.219"; // my local host ip address 
    // I want to do this only with IP address..
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+  port + "/" + dbname;
        System.out.println("URL:" + url);
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        String qry2 = "select * from atm";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry2);
        while (rs.next()) {

            name = rs.getString("name");
            System.out.println("Name:" + name);
            j.setText(""+name);

        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

When I run this I got an error:

> error>> null,  message from server: "Host 'DEEPAK-PC' is not allowed
>   to   connect to  this MySQL server"

Actually I want to make a program that takes data from another PC connected to my LAN network in school. So that's why I want to do this with IP address.

Comment: This is not a java problem. Is a MYSQL user permision related issue.
Check this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670949/remote-mysql-connection)

Answer (score 1):

you have to first grant permission to access mysql from remote location

try this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.5.219'
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some_characters'  
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

check this [mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) for more info